Can i use kibana users and role management without xpack enabled on elasticseaech nodes?
I'm running elasticsearch on 3 nodes with kibana on a seperate node. The OS is ubuntu.
version 8.11.1
I want to eliminate the headache of renewing the certificate on the servers thus i created a 2 LB vip on my staging enviornment with ssl termination for both my elastic cluster and kibana.
it's working now with easy access to renew ssl on the LB vip but i disabled xpack on my elasticsearch.yml since my servers ssl already expired
Now when i access kibana there's no RBAC on stack management. i can't modify the roles of the users accessing the indexes from my kibana ui.
After quick googling seems like i need to enable xpack on my elasticsearch.yml on the nodes.
Is there a way to avoid renewing the certifcates on the servers?
If the nodes are local and can't be accesssd out of the local network can't i be able to make them communicate with plain text and applications access them through dns and vip that have the ssl.
....................
